# How to access Density/Flame grid via Python in 2.82 (Mantaflow)

Tags: python, add-on

Does anyone know how do I access the density/flame grid for the new Mantaflow fluid simulation engine in Blender 2.82?

The old path still exists:

`bpy.context.object.modifiers["Fluid"].domain_settings.density_grid`

But this returns an empty list.

Comment: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/blender-2-8-smoke-data-empty-e-g-density-grid/8510